# Verify user identity on other computer on linux with LDAP

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ldap, grpc

I have two computers on linux. On first one user logged into system with ldap authorization and using desktop application (AvaloniaUI). On second computer service application is running. User application communicating with service using grpc. Is there any way to verify user identity on service PC without user entering password in desktop application and sending it over network? Something like getting current WindowsIdentity in Windows, sending it's token to service PC and service PC verifing that it's valid and user is who it claims.

Comment: Are the systems – and users – part of Active Directory domain or something similar?

Comment: Yes, it's part of FreeIPA

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to verify user identity on service PC without user entering password in desktop application and sending it over network? Something like getting current WindowsIdentity in Windows, sending it's token to service PC and service PC verifing that it's valid and user is who it claims.

That's called "Kerberos". When you use Windows integrated authentication in Active Directory, you aren't sending the internal Windows token – you're sending a Kerberos ticket.

The same can be done in FreeIPA, as it includes a Kerberos KDC and most of the same features. Typically on Linux it would be done through GSS-API, which is a close equivalent to Windows' SSPI (the underlying API that really powers Windows.Identity in .NET).

1. Register your service in the KDC (there's probably an ipa command for this) and receive a keytab.
2. Make sure the logged in user has Kerberos tickets (klist).
3. On the client, use GSS-API "Initiate" functions to generate a token.
4. On the server, use GSS-API "Accept" functions to validate the token. (This may require more than one pass, with the function returning another token back to the client.)

I believe dotnet has built-in Kerberos support even on Linux, avoiding the need to deal with cumbersome GSS-API directly, but I'll need to update the post once I find out. (Meanwhile, python-gssapi is really nice to get a proof-of-concept working.)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sharing all the information again, but I'm still looking and studying, as there are a lot of new things for me during the transition from Windows to Linux... It looks like we will be using gRPC to communicate between the application and the service (because gRPC looks faster and more modern than Rest. Maybe you could recommend some other modern alternative?) and Microsoft says that "Windows Authentication (NTLM/Kerberos/Negotiate) can't be used with gRPC. gRPC requires HTTP/2, and HTTP/2 doesn't support Windows Authentication."

Comment: Kerberos can be used over anything; it does not actually depend on HTTP. Sure, the *built-in* HTTP Kerberos support can't be used here if that's what the page says (although in reality, HTTP/2 does Kerberos just fine, the same way as HTTP/1, so that's actually a total lie), but it's not limited to HTTP in any way – it's a generic thing where you get a token and validate a token (it works in HTTP, IMAP, SSH, SMTP, IRC...), and you can most likely do it via gRPC all the same.